# How to change the size of MUI DateCalendar in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

I have the code to display a calendar using MUI DataCalendar.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
   <DateCalendar/>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I would like to be able to increase its size.

I tried to do the following using an `sx` property

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
       <DateCalendar
         sx={{
           "& .MuiPickersDay-root": {
             height: "100px",
             minWidth: "100px",
           },
        }}
       />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

But it doesn't display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of dirty work from what I've managed. Here is what I have, play around with the fontSizes and aspectRatios (if you're not doing 6 week view) (I am trying to get a responsive calendar), I've also got the skeleton to expand but can't get it to render every day if outsideCurrentMonth enabled or fixedWeekNum:

```html
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale={i18n.language} >
    <DateCalendar
        loading={true}
        renderLoading={() =>
            <DayCalendarSkeleton
                showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
                fixedWeekNumber={6}

            />}
        sx={{
            '& .MuiBadge-badge': {
                // Adjustment for recordMade badge 
                fontSize: '0.7em',
                paddingTop: '4px'
            },
            // '& .MuiPickersBasePicker-pickerView': {
            //     maxHeight: '800px',
            //   },

            '& .MuiDayCalendar-header': {
                // Needed for weekday (ie S M T W T F S )adjustments (and padding if wanted)
                // Adjusts spacing between
                justifyContent: 'center',
                width: '100%',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                margin: '2px, 0'
                // paddingTop: '1em',
                // paddingBottom: "1em",

            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer': {
                // Adjusts spacing between days (ie 1, 2, 3.. 27, 28)
                justifyContent: 'center',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                width: '100%',
                margin: 0
            },
            '& .MuiPickersDay-dayWithMargin': {
                // Grows width/height of day buttons
                width: 'calc(100% - 4px)',
                height: 'calc(100% - 4px)',
                aspectRatio: '1',
                // height: 'auto',

                fontSize: '1.0em',
            },
            '& .MuiBadge-root': {
                // Parent of button management
                aspectRatio: 1,
                width: '10%',
                display: 'flex',
                alignContent: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekDayLabel': {
                // Manages size of weekday labels
                aspectRatio: 1,
                width: 'calc(10% - 4px)', // deals with margin
                fontSize: '1.0em'
            },
            '& .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-label': {
                // Manages month/year size
                fontSize: '1.3em',

            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendar-monthContainer': {
                // Not sure if needed, currently works tho
                width: '100%'
            },
            '& .MuiPickersFadeTransitionGroup-root-MuiDateCalendar-viewTransitionContainer': {
                // Handles size of week row parent, 1.6 aspect is good for now
                aspectRatio: '1.6',
                overflow: 'hidden'
            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendar-slideTransition': {
                // Handles size of week row parent, 1.6 aspect is good for now
                aspectRatio: 1.6,
                width: '100%',
                overflow: 'hidden'
            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendar-loadingContainer': {
                width: '100%',
                aspectRatio: 1.6,
            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendarSkeleton-root': {
                width: '100%'
            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendarSkeleton-week': {
                width: '100%'
            },
            '& .MuiDayCalendarSkeleton-daySkeleton': {
                width: 'calc(10% - 4px) !important', // Deals with the margin calcs
                aspectRatio: '1 !important',
                height: 'auto !important'
            },

            width: '100%',
            maxHeight: '100%'
        }}


        showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
        fixedWeekNumber={6}
        views={['day']}
        onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(monthRecords);
            setRecordDate(e);
            setRecordOpen(true)
            // handleOpenEditForm(e);
        }}
        onMonthChange={(e) => {
            handleNewCalendarDates(e);
        }}
        slots={{ day: RecordedDays, }}
        slotProps={{
            day: {
                highlightedDays
            },
        }}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Made a custom skeleton actually for my case if you need it as well:

```html
renderLoading={() =>
    <div style={{ width: '100%', aspectRatio: '1.6', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }} width={'100%'} display={'flex'}>
        {
            Array.from({ length: 6 }).map((_, index) => (
            <div style={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', margin: '2px 0px' }} margin={'0px 2px'} >
                {
                    Array.from({ length: 7 }).map((_, index) => (
                        <Skeleton display='block' variant='circular' width={'calc(10% - 4px)'} height={'auto'} sx={{ aspectRatio: '1' }} style={{ margin: '0px 2px' }} key={index} />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
            ))
        }
    </div>
}
```